# Woocommerce How can I create my own new order email template?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I want to integrate the form that I designed into my email system and when it comes to order, I would like to receive mail from this form. How can I set the email template to form woocommerce that I have done this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design new order email template as per your requirement. you can go to projectfolder/themes/themename/woocommerce/emails/
 here you can add admin-new-order.php to override new order email

Comment: But there is only the hook in the main template file. How can I reach these hooks when I do the template again.

Comment: In admin-new-order.php there are some hooks like 
woocommerce_email_header,woocommerce_email_order_details,woocommerce_email_order_meta,woocommerce_email_customer_details,woocommerce_email_footer
You can override these hooks Like:
woocommerce_email_footer calls email-footer.php you can add this to projectfolder/themes/themename/woocommerce/emails/ and add as per your requirement